# Show same pages with diffrent url with nginx

Tags: nginx

is it possible to use 2 url with same page
for example :

`https://example.com/contact` has content blablabla , and we create rewrite or masking url with nginx so the final output is , when visitors hit on `https://example.com/contact2` they will see same content as `https://example.com/contact`

i've tried with nginx rewrite but the url shown is `https://example.com/contact2` not as i expected which is `https://example.com/contact`

thank you Before!

Comment: Show what you tried, then we can tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Side note: Don't do this. search engines usually decrease your score results when you present the same content with different URLs. Use redirects instead.

Comment: ok so something like this for rewrite location /contact {
   rewrite ^/.* https://example.com/contact2 permanent;
}

Comment: so for the side note , https://example.com/contact2 its only an url with no content at all on wordpress pages

Comment: Please add further information to the question with the "Edit" function in the future, so it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

The `permanent` flag makes nginx send a `301` HTTP status code to client, which makes the client load the URL specified. You might want to try `last` or `break` there, which just makes an internal rewrite inside nginx.